# Как использовать ключи типа как значения?

Tags: typescript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно воспользоваться ключами типа как значениями? к примеру:

```typescript
interface Test {
  name1: string;
  name2: string;
  name3: string;
}

function test(name: вот тут нужно передать либо 'name1', либо 'name2', по сути можно сделать 'name1' | 'name2', но это как-то хардкодно выглядит) {}
```

Comment: Если у вас 3 ключа, а вы хотите передавть 1 или 2 - то как это может быть по другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```typescript
interface Test {
  name1: string;
  name2: string;
  name3: string;
}

function test(n: keyof Test) {
    if (n === "name1") {} // ok
    if (n === "non-exising") {} // error
}
```

Это в случае если любой ключ типа `Test` должен подходить. Если некоторые (например `name3`) нужно отбросить, то можно воспользоваться `Omit`:

```typescript
interface Test {
  name1: string;
  name2: string;
  name3: string;
}

function test(n: keyof Omit<Test, "name3">) {
    if (n === "name1") {} // ok
    if (n === "name3") {} // error
}
```

Если же вы не хотите перечислять вручную все отбрасываемые значение, а вместо этого хотите наоборот передать только подходящие, то поможет `Pick`:

```typescript
interface Test {
  name1: string;
  name2: string;
  name3: string;
}

function test(n: keyof Pick<Test, ("name1" | "name2")>) {
    if (n === "name1") {} // ok
    if (n === "name3") {} // error
}
```

Но в таком случае вы особо не выигрываете по сравнению с `"name1" | "name2"`. Единственный плюс последнего решения над строковым юнионом - это что вы не сможете допустить опечатку при перечислении всех подходящих ключей.

Comment: Мне почему то каждется, что проверики `if (n === "name1")` не совсем корректны, т.к. в **n** будет содержаться значение, а не название ключа?

Comment: @SwaD благодаря оператору `keyof` не будет.

Comment: @SwaD https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLIhwC2EAjAFzJZSgDmA3AUaRAEzW0POHFkBmLmDogmeAL548MAK4gEYYAHsQySFgAUIagGsIAT2UxkABWAJdAHnRYANMk0AifhSfIAPshdt2TgJQAfP64LITAJtrIALyx3q7kAbgSyAD0qcjKumHIEY5qsdHxbAJJOCnpyNBQylCSQA

Comment: Спасибо большое, вариант через Pick больше всего заходит)

Comment: Да, я не совсем точно вопрос прочитал